# Android TextWatcher get the entire typed word

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

In my android application i have used TextWatcher, it is working fine but i need to get entire typed word instead of single letter by letter because i am saving typed value into arraylist. Note : i am creating edittext dynamically so user can update the already entered value so i need to use only TextWatcher.

My try is below

```
    public class CustomWatch implements TextWatcher {
                EditText _dynamicEd;
                Model model;
                boolean isUpdateEd = false;
                StringBuffer previousChar;
                String typedValue;
                boolean flag;

                public CustomWatch(EditText dynamic_editxt) {
                    this._dynamicEd = dynamic_editxt;
                    model = new Model();
                    previousChar = new StringBuffer();
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(_dynamicEd.getText().toString())) {
                        isUpdateEd = true;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {                                        flag = false;
                    typedValue = s.toString();
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(!flag) {
                                Log.d("Timer", "value-->" + s.toString());
 model.setName(s.toString());
                Controllers.getInstance().modellist.add(model);
                Controllers.getInstance().getPreferenceManager(MainActivity.this).saveProductList("CHECK_LIST", Controllers.getInstance().modellist);
                c++;
                                flag = true;
                            }else{

                            }
                        }
                    },2000);

                }
            }
```

Comment: you mean _dynamicEd.getText()?

Comment: yes that edittext is dynamically created one. i have used custom TextWatcher class to pass

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: check my updated question

Comment: what is `entire typed word `? what is your `word` definition? any set of characters delimited by what?

Comment: say an example : i am typing the word ENGLISH, then i am getting E,EN,ENG. instead of that i need entire word ENGLISH.

Comment: wait, you entered only "ENG" and you want to get "ENGLISH" ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `dynamic_editxt.getText()` Inside `afterTextChanged`

Comment: If this is not what you need i dont understand your question

Answer (score 0):

It may work,

```
@Override
  public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
    if(s.contains("\\s")){
     String[] words = s.toString().split("\\s+");
     //Code to add words to the list
   }
 }
```

**Update :**

As your requirements you can add the whole sentence in arraylist by getting the focus of `EditText` like here

```
 myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
      if (!hasFocus) {
       //Here user finished the typing, Now save userTypedValue as required
      String userTypedValue = myEditText.getText().toString();
      }
    }
 });
```

Comment: what it will do exactly ??/

Comment: aren't you willing to save the words that user typed in Edittext to an arraylist ?

Comment: i have a custom arraylist. i need to save entire typed value into my arraylist instead of letter by letter. kindly check my code once.

Comment: Then you can save that after the user finishes typing.

Comment: yeah thats what how can i find that the user has finished his typing. because every editext has created dynamically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108244/discussion-between-madhu-and-shree-krishna).

Comment: @Madhu last edittext value means ? will you make it clear ? You mean other remaining edittext's values are retrieved ?